# Jira report generation using prefix

Tags: report, jira

Can Jira generate a report using task prefix or some tag even if the tasks are in different projects? I have heard that it is possible but i cannot find any information about it. 
I want to produce a report based on specific prefix for all hours spent on research for example (in all projects or just the projects with specific prefixes)

Comment: What kind of report do you want to produce?

Comment: check edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate reports based on a filter (a query that you saved earlier) that fetches issues from different projects.